# Android: unable to load XML

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-studio

New Android Studio Project

Created Assets folder

Create constructor of new activity (second in the project) to read XML when the activity is called.

put the xml file I want read in the assets folder i created

Here is the code to read the xml

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream xmlFile= assetManager.open("menu.xml");

    // CREATE BUILDER FACTORY/BUILDER
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);

    //Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    //Log.d("root element",root.getNodeName());

    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("subcategory");

    Log.d("NODE", String.valueOf(list.getLength()));
```

When running the app, the button is called to bring up the new activity, but crashes... 
Please help

Here is logcat output

```
07-28 15:52:30.138    6990-6990/com.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:74)
            at com.app.MainMenu.<init>(MainMenu.java:60)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainACtivity is a default android studio activity with a button to call the new activity
MainMenu is the second activity that calls the XML

please advise.

thank you!

Comment: where did you place the assets folder in your project architecture?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:74)

Check if getAssets() is returning some value.

Comment: @Rocel assets folder was created in the default path src/main/assets (specified in conf file app.iml)

Comment: @user3586222 What's the best way to check if getassets is returning something? Can you provide code example?

Comment: Debugging the project.

Comment: Yah, that didn't help.

Comment: I took some debug code out of the constructor I created (that was not working) and added it to the onCreate method instead and it worked fine.  Is this a fundamental problem (possibly of mine) in creating a constructor and using it, instead of using the onCreate method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call getAssets() for whatever context your activity is in,

context.getAssets();

Comment: I added this.getAssets(); Same problem.